# Way to get around integer requirements of g2.drawLine() method

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel

I am currently trying to draw a line and keep the line proportionally the same no matter how the user resizes the JFrame. However, the problem I run into is when I try to draw a line when the user makes the JFrame smaller than the default value, as I end up multiplying the coordinates by fractions under 1, and since g2.drawLine() requires integers, it takes them as 0's and nothing is drawn. I'm wondering if there's a work-around to this little glitch or if you guys have any suggestions of how I should change my logic.

Comment: FYI: Beware of re-posting a question you've not gotten an answer to yet - it's not really encouraged. I might take a few days before you get an answer you're satisfied with

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's not the same question - the previous one was when I had no clue how to do this, but this one is me having problems with one of the ways of implementations I tried out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're seeing is just because of integer division. See [*Why is the result of `1/3 == 0`?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685450/2891664). When you have `(width / 624)`, the result of this is always 0 if `width` is less than 624.

You could:

- use `(width / 624.0)`, which performs the division in floating-point (as `double`), or
- you could rearrange your parentheses to be e.g. `(int) ((x * width) / 624))` instead of `(int) (x * (width / 624))`.

However, to answer the question directly, you can draw a line with floating-point coordinates by using [`java.awt.geom.Line2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html):

```
Line2D line2D = new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2);
graphics2D.draw(line2D);
```

(Also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html.)

Answer (score 0):

> multiplying the coordinates by fractions under 1, and since
>   g2.drawLine() requires integers, it takes them as 0's

That's obviously false! If a coordinates is say, 327, then multiplying it by say 0.7 gives 228.9. That's not an integer but is has integer part, so you can safely convert it to integer:

```
double factor = ...;
int newCoord, oldCoord = ...;
newCoord = (int)(oldCoord * factor)
```

will give you the rounded result.

**Or** something else is wrong...